# pathinfo() working on localhost but not on the live server

Tags: php

```
$name = pathinfo($num)['filename']; this is line 15.
```

The error:

> [25-Sep-2013 05:32:00] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /xxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/Project/mainpage.php on line 15.

The same code works perfectly on localhost with XAMP!

Any other way which I should try ?

Comment: Probably the version of your PHP does not support the extra `[...]` what PHP you have on the server?

Comment: check if the `pathinfo` is enable in your `php.ini`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error might be occurring because, `pathinfo($num)` is not an array.
Please update it to:

```
<?php
$pInfo = pathinfo($num);
$name = '';
if (! empty($pInfo) && is_array($pInfo)) {
  $name = $pInfo['filename']; //this is line 15.
}
?>
```

Comment: @Amol the code you wrote does solve the problem, but the explanation you gave isn't correct. That error is caused due to an invalid syntax in PHP below 5.4.

Comment: :) @EduardLuca, you are correct. I suggested my answer. Your answer is more correct than me.

Answer (score 1):

What PHP version do you have on the server? Probably less than 5.4. And on localhost you probably have 5.4.

That is the problem. A syntax like `pathinfo($num)['filename']` is only valid in PHP 5.4.

Either upgrade PHP on the server, or do as Amol suggested.

Comment: @Prix sorry, but no :) If that were the case, a notice or warning would have been thrown, because the `filename` index didn't exist. Here we're dealing with a syntax error, which means the PHP script wasn't even executed.